# Помогите разобраться с Inline кнопкой

Tags: python, aiogram

код:

```
 @dp.message_handler(text='Профиль')
async def profile_user(message: types.Message):
    info_user = {
        'Username': message.from_user.username,
        'first name': message.from_user.first_name,
        'ID user': message.from_user.id,
        'Primary': 'NO',
    }

    full_info = f"<b>User name</b>: {info_user['Username']}\n" \
                f"<b>First name</b>: {info_user['first name']}\n" \
                f"<b>ID</b>: {info_user['ID user']}\n" \
                f"<b>Prime</b>: {info_user['Primary']}"

    inlineKEYBOD = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    button_inl = [types.InlineKeyboardButton('Пополнить баланс', callback_data="add money"), types.InlineKeyboardButton('Купить Прайм', callback_data='q2'),
                  types.InlineKeyboardButton('История покупок', callback_data='q3'), types.InlineKeyboardButton('История пополнений', callback_data='q4')]

    inlineKEYBOD.add(button_inl[0], button_inl[1])
    inlineKEYBOD.add(button_inl[2], button_inl[3])

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                           full_info,
                           reply_markup=inlineKEYBOD,
                           parse_mode='html')

  @dp.callback_query_handler()
async def handlers_call(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):

    if callback_query.data == 'add money':
        payment_acceptance = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        button = [types.InlineKeyboardButton('BitcoinRU', callback_data='w2'),
                  types.InlineKeyboardButton('Payeer', callback_data='w1'),
                  types.InlineKeyboardButton('Payok', url='')]
        payment_acceptance.add(button[0], button[1], button[2])
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, text="<b>Выберите способ оплаты</b>",
                               reply_markup=payment_acceptance, parse_mode='html')
```

ПОчему выходит ошибка при нажатии кнопки???

aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse inline keyboard button: text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard